# Trigger completion within GHCi when using :main

Tags: haskell, ghci, bash-completion

I'm using the optparse-applicative library, which supports Bash-completion. I'd like to trigger such completion when typing `:main <tab>` within GHCi. Is there a way to instruct GHCi to use the current `main` function to propose such completion ?

Comment: Related request: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21564. So far as I know people showed interest in these kinds of completion features, but I don't think anybody attempted an implementation yet. Perhaps you'd like to give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. GHCI isn't Bash, so a binary's Bash completion support won't be easily applied. If you look at [how completion support works](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.18.1.0#bash-zsh-and-fish-completions), you'll see it outputs a script to be sourced in a Bash session; I don't see how you would apply such a thing inside of GHCI.

Comment: I have hooked optparse-applicative support for completion (using its mechanism intended for Bash) to Haskeline in the past. I guess I only need a little trick on the GHCi side to do something similar.